# asp.net core 2 MySQL Driver 3.51 ODBC is needed?

Tags: mysql, odbc, asp.net-core-2.0

I don't quite understand this driver thing for DB's.

First I was trying to connect DB using PHP normally using "mysql" methods but I was receiving error to update password for DB user as it was old MySQL. But I cant change it or upgrade MySQL so I found that in PHP I can use PDO and ODBC to use MySQL driver 3.51 and it works.

Now I want to rewrite back-end to asp.net Core 2. Where I found that there is no ODBC. How can I connect to DB? Can I use MySQL.DATA ? If yes how do I provide driver to it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the last time I checked MySQL.Data does not have any stable (non prerelease) version to connect .net core to MySQL. However their prerelease versions work just fine. I have used it with a number of applications and faced no bugs yet. There are 4 ways to install the prerelease. You can pick any one:

1. In visual studio nuget manager, mark Include prerelease check box and then update MySQL.Data to the latest version.
2. In your Package Manager Console in visual studio, enter the following code to install the latest prerelease

`Install-Package MySql.Data -Version 8.0.8-dmr`

3. In command prompt, cd to your project location and use the following code for the latest prerelease

`dotnet add package MySql.Data --version 8.0.8-dmr`

4. Manually download your preferred version from here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/

As of making the connection, I use the following format for the connection string.

`Server=;Uid=;Database=;password=;SslMode=none`

Comment: Thanks, that helps :) no Im getting same error like in PHP before I used ODBC - "MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Authentication with old password no longer supported, use 4.1 style passwords." so I know that Im on the good way to solve it. Maybe you know how to solve it? Of course as I mention it, I cant change password. It would be to simple :P

Comment: well according to this link https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,593423,593431#msg-593431  the new versions discontinued allowing the old password format. and as i was saying .net core only supports the new versions of mysql.data
you can look into the link within the link if that helps. 
If you can't alter the db in any way, your only option is to use the password in the right format

Comment: yea, I saw that. Eh so the only way will be to force this change from DB side... I'm not sure if company will agree for that but we'll see :) Thanks  Neville Nazerane for help

Comment: i think according to the link you can pass the old password in different format in .net core without making changes in the db